# Array in function increment / decrement

Tags: javascript

Добавить в массив операцию декремента инкремента, чтобы результат операции был такой:

```
[2, 3, 9, 0, 9].increment()    // [2, 3, 9, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].decrement() // [9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Вам дали несколько ответов, ни один из них не решает вашу задачу?

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, упустил какие-то граничные условия, но на вскидку, должно работать

```js
Array.prototype.inc = function () {
    if( ! this.length) return [1];
    var t = 1;
    for(var i=this.length; --i>=0;) {
       t = this[i]+t;
       this[i] = t % 10;
       t = Math.floor(t / 10);
    }
    if(t)  this.unshift(t)
    return this;
}    

Array.prototype.dec = function () {
    if( ! this.length) return [-1];
    var t = 1;
    for(var i=this.length; --i>=0;) {
       t = this[i]-t;
       if(t < 0) {
           this[i] = t + 10;
           t = 1 
       }
       else {
           this[i] = t;
           t = 0; 
       } 
    }
    if(t) return [-1];
    return this;
}    

console.log([2, 3, 9, 0, 9].inc()) // [2, 3, 9, 1, 0]
console.log([9].inc()) // [1, 0]
console.log([2, 3, 9, 0, 0].dec()) // [2, 3, 8, 9, 9]
console.log([0].dec()) // [-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Наполовину похоже на вариант господина @Deonis, только сумма находится сверткой, а не через преобразование к строке

```js
Array.prototype.dec = function() {
  return String(-1 + this.reduce((a, i) => a*10 + i)).split('').map(Number)
};

Array.prototype.inc = function() {
  return String(1 + this.reduce((a, i) => a*10 + i)).split('').map(Number)
};


console.log(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5].dec()))
console.log(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5].inc()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Остаётся вопрос, что делать, например, в таком случае - `[-2, 3, -9, 0, 9]`, но предложу еще такой вариант:

```js
Array.prototype.increment = function() {
  return (+this.join('') + 1).toString().match(/-?\d/g).map(Number);
};
Array.prototype.decrement = function() {
  return (+this.join('') - 1).toString().match(/-?\d/g).map(Number);
};

console.log([2, 3, 9, 0, 9].increment());
console.log([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].decrement());
```

Comment: а я не догадался в число собрать, одно оправдание, что на любой длине массива работать будет :)

Comment: @splash58, не завидуйте, т.к. мой вариант далек от идеала ))